# history.back() not working after ajax success function

Tags: jquery, ajax, double-click

I want after `Ajax success function` I could return to the previous page.

```
<div id="dialog" title="Complain">
       <form id="komenform">
                <label>Model :</label>
                <input type="text" id="comodel" name="comodel"/>
                <label>Komentar :</label>
                <textarea id="comment" name="comment" rows="5" cols="20" ></textarea>
                <button id="submitcom" type="button" class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all"><span>Submit </span></button>
                <input name="action" value="inputcom" type="hidden">
       </form>
</div>

$("#komenform").validate({
        rules:{
                comodel:{
                          required:true
                          },
                comment:{
                        required:true
                        }
                }
        });

$("#submitcom").click(function() {
      if($("#komenform").valid()) {
            var params=$("#komenform").serialize();
            $.ajax({
                    type:"post",
                    url:"/QA/process2.php",
                    data:params,
                    cache :false,
                    async :false,
                    success : function() {
                           $("#comodel").val("");
                           $("#comment").val("");
                           $("#dialog").dialog('close');
                           history.back();
                           },
                    error : function() {
                           alert("Data failed to input.");
                           }
                    });
            }
      });
```

But it won't work.

---

**UPDATE**

it works after I try to remove `dialog('close')`:

```
success : function() {
       $("#comodel").val("");
       $("#comment").val("");
 //      $("#dialog").dialog('close');
       window.history.go(-1);
       return false;
       },
```

but, I need to double click on submit button. why?

Comment: This might sound silly, but you're not performing an asynchronous request there. So why bother using AJAX? Wouldn't it be better to submit the form to a PHP page and then use `header()` instead?

Comment: It **should** work, unless history.back() does not find anything to go back to (ie, there is no previous page or the previous page is the same as the current page). What happens exactly? HAve you tried to `console.log()` something from inside your success function?

Comment: Are you using the back button to keep certain info saved on the previous page, like input fields? If so, you may want to consider an alternative way to preserving the data, such as cookies or URL variables.

If you are trying to prevent the page from changing when submitting the form, then add `return false;` at the end of your `.click(function(){`

Comment: it works just until `dialog('close')`.I'm just have idea using Ajax may be someone could give me some advise.

Comment: Have you tried : `history.go(-1)`, though they are essentially same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it works..

```
success : function() {
       $("#comodel").val("");
       $("#comment").val("");
 //      $("#dialog").dialog('close');
       window.history.go(-2);
       return false;
       },
```

just change `-1` into `-2`.

Answer (score 1):

Suggestions:

- I don't find any use of AJAX here because of async:false
- Call PHP page and using header redirect to your desired page
- Debug your code by console.log once ajax call succeeds
- try window.history.back() instead of history.back()

Comment: [cycle] terminating; zero elements found by selector

Comment: can you tell more about which page you are trying to go back.. check whether you are in the first page and trying to go back

Comment: still not working.this page (which have dialog) is link page after click some button in previous page.

Comment: try window.history.back() instead of history.back()